# Erro ao executar um assert no eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, selenium-webdriver

Tenho as seguintes linhas:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

 public class ClasseTeste extends Navegadores {
  public static void verificarTitulo() {
     abrirChrome();
     String titulo = driver.getTitle();
     assertTrue(titulo.contains("google"));
     fecharNavegador(); 
  }
}
```

Então quanto executo o main:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
     verificarTitulo();     
}
```

Isso ocorre:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/Assert  
    at teste.NovoProjeto.ClasseTeste.verificarTitulo(ClasseTeste.java:11)  
    at teste.NovoProjeto.Main.main(Main.java:8)  
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.Assert  
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)  
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)  
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)  
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  
    ... 2 more
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar nessa?

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` indica que o JUnit não está no classpath do seu projeto. Você está certo de que ele está lá?

Comment: Como você está importando o JUnit? Via Maven ou jar import? Explique por gentileza como está estruturado o seu projeto.
At.

Comment: É um projeto Maven, todas as classes estão no pacote main. Pra importar eu só adicionei essas linhas no pom: <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>4.10</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema provavelmente ocorre porque o seu JUnit está como dependência de teste:

```xml
<scope>test</scope>`
```

Isso significa que ele somente vai estar disponível quando você estiver executando um teste, por exemplo, executando um comando `mvn test` no projeto.

No entanto, o método `main` usado revela que você não está executando o teste realmente como um teste, mas sim como um programa normal.

Para executar realmente testes unitários você deve criar uma classe em `src/test/java`. Pode ser em qualquer pacote, ams tem que ser dentro desse diretório. Então crie métodos públicos e não estáticos anotados com `@Test`.

Exemplo:

```java
@Test
public void testarTitulo() {
    ...    
}
```

Então, para executar os métodos das classes de teste, você deve digitar o comando `mvn test` no console para que o Maven execute os testes. Se estiver usando uma IDE como Eclipse, também é possível executar as classes de teste clicando nelas com o botão direito e acessando o menu `Run as > Junit Test`.

Leia um pouco mais sobre testes unitários [aqui](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html).

Comment: Caí aqui porque ao usar o escopo `test` para o junit apareciam erros de compilação no Eclipse (como se eu não tivesse a dependência no classpath), o problema era porque a classe com os testes unitários não estava dentro de `src/test/java`!